# Change font size of notebook tabs in ruby tk

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

Using ruby (1.9.1) with tk, I am creating a simple notebook/tab page.

I want to change the font of the tabs and haven't found a way to do that yet, though I know it can be done in other languages.

Here's some simple base code:

```
root = TkRoot.new
root.title = "Window"
myFont = TkFont.new("family" => 'Helvetica', "size" => 20)
tabs = TkNotebook.new(root) { height 100 }.pack
tab1 = TkFrame.new(tabs)
tab2 = TkFrame.new(tabs)
tabs.add tab1, text: "Tab 1"
tabs.add tab2, text: "Tab 2"

Tk.mainloop
```

Where can I set the tabs to use 'myFont'?

Comment: The style for the notebook tab is named `TNotebook.Tab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Brad Lanam's hint in the comments I learned about Tk themes and styling, so the answer in code is:

```
Tk::Tile::Style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', {font: "helvetica 22"})
```

And then you can, for example, also add padding with:

```
Tk::Tile::Style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', {padding: "15 3 15 3"})
```

(And to get the "TNotebook" as the style, you can do "TkWinfo.classname(obj)" on a TkNotebook object - though I don't know how you figure out that it's the "TNotebook.Tab" you need to target, probably need to find that in the docs instead of with inspection)

Thanks for the help!